Stylus css Loop Prop : Value with css variables
I'm trying to create a class that has the variables above the code, and the properties below
I have created a loop, but it does not work when compiling the css
Here is the stylus css code
//lista_vars = --b-bg-color: #008000, --b-color: #f00 //error
lista_vars = {--b-bg-color: #008000}, {--b-color: #f00}
lista_props = 'background-color: var(--b-bg-color)', 'color: var(--b-color)'

LoopValues(values)
    for value in values
        value
        p(value[0]) 

body
    LoopValues(lista_vars)
    LoopValues(lista_props)
    //p(lista_vars)
    //p(lista_props)

This is an example of the CSS code I want to obtain
.b {
  /*here vars*/
  --b-bg-color: #008000;
  --b-color: #f00
  /*here props*/
  background-color: var(--b-bg-color)
  color: var(--b-color)
}

But when I compile it it doesn't show me anything
